# CosmosDB mongodb - $all combined with $elemMatch query on nested collection of objects not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using CosmosDB (with mongodb-api).

For this example I'm using the next documents:

```css
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "abspi4lxwfbfjahdvjm3clnnl4",
    "categories" : [ 
        {
            "_name" : "category-1",
            "date" : NumberLong(1540373282070),
            "string" : "20",
            "number" : 20
        }, 
        {
            "_name" : "category-2",
            "string" : "1",
            "number" : 1
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "ggi36vpvprdbrdnji5otypbh3e",
    "categories" : [ 
        {
            "_name" : "category-2",
            "date" : NumberLong(1540373282071),
            "string" : "1",
            "number" : 1
        }
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "kdh3jdyenapq54clufgajmgfy8",
    "categories" : [ 
        {
            "_name" : "category-1",
            "date" : NumberLong(1540373282070),
            "string" : "20",
            "number" : 20
        }, 
        {
            "_name" : "category-2",
            "string" : "1",
            "number" : 1
        },
        {
            "_name" : "category-3",
            "string" : "29",
            "number" : 29
        }
    ]
}
```

I need retrieve the documents 1 and 3, the next query match works perfectly in mongoDB.

```css
db.getCollection('test_collection')
    .find({"categories":{
        "$all":[
            {"$elemMatch":{"number":20}},
            {"$elemMatch":{"number":1}}
        ]
     }
})
```

In CosmosDB return 0 records.It seems that more than 1 elemMatch in cosmosDB is not supported.
Any idea if its is possible do the query in CosmosDB with mongoDB-api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was been resolved for the new databases created at end of october 2018.
We did much test for test the compatibilty and works fine.

This time we have been lucky, had been thinking change all system to documentDB with SQL query.

I hope that post help other people that maybe will be in same situation.

Answer (score 0):

> In CosmosDB return 0 records.It seems that more than 1 elemMatch in
>   cosmosDB is not supported.

Yes, based on my test, combination of `$and` operator and more that 1 elemMatch conditions is not supported in the Cosmos Mongo API. Per my knowledge, CosmosDB just supports a subset of the MongoDB API and translates requests into the CosmosDB SQL equivalent. CosmosDB has some different behaviours and results. But the onus is on CosmosDB to improve their emulation of MongoDB.

Certainly, you could add feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to submit your requirements or consider using [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/microsoft-azure/) on Azure if you'd like full MongoDB feature support.

Comment: Thank for your response @JayGong, I was speaking a day ago with CosmosDB team and they said, that the issue has been fix this very month,but only applies for new databases.

My team have been testing today, much combinations and seem the new feature works fine.